# CakePHP: Tree list scaffold

Tags: php, cakephp, foreign-key-relationship, scaffolding, treelist

I have a SQL table called `Sections` with the following columns

```
Id | Name | Parent_id
```

I had generated the code with `cake bake`.

The problem is that if you add a new section, I cannot choose the parent category. It works only when the controller uses scaffolding.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should read the [CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/907/Developing-with-CakePHP) if you want to move on from scaffolding. But I try to give you a few clues to help you get started.

First of all you have to follow [CakePHP conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions) and name tables, columns, classes, properties,... the right way. So unless you were overriding and customizing things a lot, you should end with a `sections` table with `id`, `name` and `parent_id` columns.

If you want to establish a relationship between models you have to [build two models](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1001/Understanding-Models) (`Section` and `Parent` in this case) and [configure their relationships](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together).

Having all this accomplished you can then build your forms using the [`FormHelper`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1383/Form) and [saving everything](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) using the appropriate methods of your models.